# Function not changing image in gallery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an image gallery using vanilla JavaScript. I'm trying to make it so that clicking on a thumbnail will change the `src`attribute in the `img` tag with the class `gallery-highlight`, updating the image shown to the user. But when I open my HTML file in Firefox and click on an image thumbnail, it does nothing. My JavaScript doesn't seem to be doing anything to the page. How can I fix this?

Here's what I've got:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1.0" />
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="./efrain-big.jpg" class="gallery-highlight" alt="" />
    <div class="room-preview">
        <img src="./efrain-small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="./heather-small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="./jimmy-small.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function imageGallery() {
    const highlight = document.querySelector(".gallery-highlight");
    const previews = document.querySelectorAll(".room-preview img");
    
    previews.forEach(preview => {
        preview.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const smallSrc = this.src;
            const bigSrc = smallSrc.replace('small', 'big');
            
            highlight.src = bigSrc;
        });
    });
}

imageGallery();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you init your JS properly? Because it looks like that your code is working properly on https://jsfiddle.net/q5wpzjk3/

Comment: @PatrikDendis how would I init it properly? I thought just linking the script file in my HTML file should do the job

Comment: Can you call your function imageGallery() from 
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
})
?

Comment: Another options is just move <script src="./script.js"></script> before </body>

Comment: @PatrikDendis none of those did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the way you organized your project. From what can i see ( the HTML code) you happen to have all the files in one folders. No subfolders for js and css. If that’s not the case you need to fix the src of js in the script tag .

Comment: The files _are_ all in one folder, I don't think that's what the problem is.

Comment: Try using:

    documnent.getElementsByClass("");

sometime querySelectors causes unexpected errors.

Comment: refactored it with this in mind, still doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/jpaul121/zbft0174/8/

Comment: Your example is workingh just fine. Whenever i click on an image it changes to the main image. That's what you wanted to do ?

Comment: I feel like I must be crazy, but the example in my last comment is not working for me. I wonder why that is